# How can pause and play video?

Tags: javascript, ajax, video-streaming

Actually i am working on IPTV
what i want is if i pause any video i must be able to capture the moment at which it is which may be in main TV page and now if click another button it must open a small iframe which contain the same video but resumes from the same instance where it is turned to small iframe.

Please suggest some solutions.
 Thanks

Comment: it depends how you're playing the video: flash, html5 or even quicktime or windows media plugin?

Answer (score 0):

How is the video played?  I’m afraid your question is too vague for us to be able to help you.

Using Flash?  ActionScript has an `ExternalInterface` that talks with JavaScript.  With hash tags (`page#tag:tag`), you can access `document.location.hash` from JavaScript, do some custom deserialization (if you embed more than a simple piece of string) and pass that information to any Flash object in the page.

Whether your video player supports seeking is another story.